# finding the coefficient k of a joint pdf $f(x,y)$ under the multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

given the joint pdf $f(x,y) = $

$$k e^{-\frac12(x^2-2xy+5y^2)},$$

find $k.$

I understand that there is some trick to computing $k$ using properties of the multivariate normal distribution, but have no clue where to start.

Comment: The accepted answer contains a mistake $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2y^2}=2\sqrt {2\pi}$$.  In fact, [$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2y^2}=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+e%5E%7B-2x%5E2%7D+dx,+x%3D-oo..oo).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac 1 2 (x^2-2xy+5y^2)} \, dx \, dy =\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac 1 2 ((x-y)^2+4y^2)} \, dx \, dy. $$

Integrate with respect to $x$ first  and note that

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac 1 2 ((x-y)^2)} \, dx =\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac 1 2 x^2} \,dx =\sqrt {2\pi}.
$$

Now $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2y^2}=2\sqrt {2\pi}$$ as seen by the substitution $y=2z$. Hence $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac 1 2 (x^2-2xy+5y^2)} \, dx \, dy =4\pi$$ and the value of the constant $k$ is $\dfrac 1 {4\pi}$.

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned the double integral method was not the method my unit convenor wants to see, hence why the integral is hard to compute, instead it has to do with some way of manipulating the multivariate normal distribution function. I know that is me being vague but I just know there is another way of solving it.

Comment: I added small spaces before $dx$ and $dy.$ That is standard usage.

Comment: The bivariate normal density is
$$\begin{align}
& f(x,y) \\[10pt]
= {} &
      \frac{1}{2 \pi  \sigma_X \sigma_Y \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}
      \exp\left(
        -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[
          \frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{\sigma_X^2} +
          \frac{(y-\mu_Y)^2}{\sigma_Y^2} -
          \frac{2\rho(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}
        \right]
      \right).
\end{align}$$
where $\rho$ is the correlation between $X$ and $Y.$

Comment: In your case the expected values are $\mu_X=\mu_Y=0,$ so we have
$$\begin{align}
f(x,y) & = \frac 1 {2\pi \sigma_X \sigma_Y \sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \exp\left( -\frac 1 {2(1-\rho^2)} \left[ \frac{x^2}{\sigma_X^2} + \frac{y^2}{\sigma_Y^2} - \frac{2\rho xy}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y} \right] \right) \\ \\
& = \frac 1 {2\pi \sigma_X \sigma_Y \sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \exp\left( -\frac 1 {2(1-\rho^2)} \left[ \frac{\sigma_Y^2 x^2 + \sigma_X^2 y^2 - 2\rho\sigma_X\sigma_Y xy}{\sigma_X^2 \sigma_Y^2} \right] \right).
\end{align} $$ Thus we have $(1-\rho^2)\sigma_X^2\sigma_Y^2 = 2. \qquad$

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for, thank you. How can you tell that μX=μY=0? Additionally, how would you then go about showing that X ~ _N_ (0, 5/4) and Y ~ _N_ (0, 1/4) ?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Why did you reject Jozef Milenkiewicz's proposed edit?  This is just a ["minor technical correction"](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10053/290189) which "can be made without further discussion".  See [Wolfram's output](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+e%5E%7B-2x%5E2%7D+dx,+x%3D-oo..oo).

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2y^2}=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}$$ See Wolfram's link in my previous comment.