# given a joint pdf, find the distribution parameters and corr(X,Y)

Tags: statistics

given the joint PDF:

$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{4π} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2-2xy+5y^2)}$$

a) show that $X \sim N(0, 5/4)$ and $Y \sim N(0, 1/4)$

b) find $\operatorname{corr}(X,Y)$ and show whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

c) what are expected values and how can you conclude $μX = μY = 0$ for this PDF

I understand that a) can be shown by utilizing the properties of the multivariate normal distribution but don't know how to arrive at an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Correction.

The joint PDF should be
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2-2xy+5y^2\right)\right).
$$
Otherwise,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f_{X,Y}(x,y){\rm d}x{\rm d}y\ne 1,
$$
making $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ no longer a PDF.

> (a) Given the joint PDF $f_{X,Y}$, find the marginal PDFs $f_X$ and $f_Y$.

According to the definition, provided the joint PDF $f_{X,Y}=f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, the marginal PDF of $X$ (i.e., $f_X$) reads
\begin{align}
f_X(x)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X,Y}(x,y){\rm d}y\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2-2xy+5y^2\right)\right){\rm d}y\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{10\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{2}{5}x^2\right).
\end{align}
Compare this result with the PDF of normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\left(x-\mu\right)^2}{\sigma^2}\right),
$$
and it is clear that
$$
X\sim\mathcal{N}\Bigl(0,\frac{5}{4}\Bigr).
$$

Similarly, the marginal PDF of $Y$ (i.e., $f_Y$) reads
\begin{align}
f_Y(y)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X,Y}(x,y){\rm d}x\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2-2xy+5y^2\right)\right){\rm d}x\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp\left(-2y^2\right).
\end{align}
Again, compare this result to the PDF of normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and it is clear that
$$
Y\sim\mathcal{N}\Bigl(0,\frac{1}{4}\Bigr).
$$

> Find the correlation coefficient between $X$ and $Y$.

According to the definition,
\begin{align}
\text{corr}\left(X,Y\right)&=\frac{\mathbb{E}\left(X-\mu_X\right)\left(Y-\mu_Y\right)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}=\frac{\mathbb{E}XY}{\sqrt{5/4}\sqrt{1/4}}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}\mathbb{E}XY\\
&=\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}xyf_{X,Y}(x,y){\rm d}x{\rm d}y\\
&=\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}xy\frac{1}{\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2-2xy+5y^2\right)\right){\rm d}x{\rm d}y\\
&=\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}.
\end{align}
Since $X$ and $Y$ are Pearson-correlated, they must be dependent random variables.

(I did not get what part (c) was asking about...)

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your correction, I got the 1/4*pi from asking about that in a separate question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2752579/finding-the-coefficient-k-of-a-joint-pdf-fx-y-under-the-multivariate-normal

Comment: @JozefMilenkiewicz: Hopefully you did not vote for that answer. It is incorrect. $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-2y^2}{\rm d}y=\sqrt{2\pi}/2$; it should not be $2\sqrt{2\pi}$. In that question, $k=1/\pi$ is the correct answer.

Comment: also finally, how would you find the conditional distribution of Y where X = 0

Comment: @JozefMilenkiewicz: Still from the definition, the PDF of $Y|X$ reads $$f_{Y|X}(x,y)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x,y)}=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X,Y}(x,y){\rm d}y}.$$Upon the completion of this calculation, let $x=0$ would do. You may find more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution).